# Display Ads after every nth iteration in #each MeteorJs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, google-ad-manager

I'm quite new to meteor blaze. I want to know how it's possible to display something (an advert) after a particular number of iteration in meteorjs. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

And what about doing this within the js helper? I did it in this way.

```
Template.foo.helpers({

 stuffWithAds : function(){

   col = GivenCollection.find().fetch();
   toTemplate = [];

   for(i=0; i<col.length; i++){

      toTemplate.push(col[i]);

      if (i % 2 != 0){

        toTemplate.push('whatever you want to insert');

      }

   }

  return toTemplate;  }

});
```

This inserts whatever you want after  2 elements.